# Equals method does not return true for same object

Tags: java, spring

```
@IdClass=(value = TripleKey.class)
class Triple {
   String subject;
   String predicate;
   String object;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        if (!super.equals(o)) return false;

        Triple triple = (Triple) o;

        if (!subject.equals(triple.subject)) return false;
        return predicate.equals(triple.predicate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + subject.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + predicate.hashCode();
        return result;
    }
}
```

my objects are:

```
{
    "subject": "http://www.someurl.com/thing/resources/<owner>#SenMLJSON",
    "predicate": "probes_in",
    "object":"http://sweet.jpl.nasa.gov/2.3/matrSediment.owl#clay"

}
```

and

```
{
        "subject": "http://www.someurl.com/thing/resources/<owner>#SenMLJSON",
        "predicate": "probes_in",
        "object":"http://sweet.jpl.nasa.gov/2.3/matrSediment.owl#sand"

    }
```

When I try the following I still have duplicates :

```
public static List<Triple> mergeTripleLists(List<Triple> oldList, List<Triple> newList) {
        Set<Triple> tripleSet = new HashSet<>(oldList);
        tripleSet.removeAll(newList);
        tripleSet.addAll(newList);
        return new ArrayList<>(tripleSet);

    }
```

Comment: I see no calls to the equals. have you debugged it and checked where or why it gives a different result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in:

```
if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
```

If should work after removing it.

Comment: weird thing is it was generated with inteliJ -> generate-> equals hashcode-> IntelliJ Default

Comment: @Arno_Geismar And, as said in other answers, you need remove `super.hashCode` method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the call to the equals method of the super class which uses object reference to test equality, so remove the line with

```
!super.equals(o)
```

You also need to remove the call to the hashCode method of the super class.